# How to mark the special case as success for "failed to load application context"

Tags: spring, junit, junit4, spring-test

Normally when failed to load application context, it means the test case failed.

However, sometimes I need to specially trigger "failed to load application context" for rainy cases and I need to mark this kind of case as a success. How can we do this using spring-test/junit ?

Thanks!